# Install Magento 2 on different mysql port

Tags: magento-2.1, database, installation, nginx, cli

I have my nginx running on port 8080 and mysql running on port 3307. I want to install magento 2 cloned from git using CLI. Any idea how to configure the database which will use the port number 3307.

Can I just put `--db-host = "localhost:3307"`? Will this work for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

```
--db-host=localhost:3307
```

> Note: You can optionally specify the database server port in its host
>   name like www.example.com:9000

in your case: **localhost:3307**

Answer (score 3):

Incase you already installed via CLI, but you can change later on env.php

```
       'connection' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'dbname' => '****',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '*****',
            'model' => 'mysql4',
            'engine' => 'innodb',
            'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
            'active' => '1'
        ]
    ]
```

to

```
'connection' => [
    'default' => [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1:3307',
        'dbname' => '****',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '*****',
        'model' => 'mysql4',
        'engine' => 'innodb',
        'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
        'active' => '1'
    ]
]
```

Just add port number in 'host'